# Transmitting data with post method with an ESP8266 in micropython but nothing in the DBB

Tags: php, sql, esp8266, micropython

I'm trying to send data on a MySQL DDB with an esp8266.

I sent data with a post method. I preparer the data on the ESP, I use the post method  in order to sent the data to my web page. My web page in php will send the data to the DBB.

*Here you can read the code on the ESP8266 , it's micropython*

```
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep
import dht
import urequests
import wifimgr
import json

capteur = dht.DHT11(Pin(10))
wlan = wifimgr.get_connection()

while True:
    try:
        sleep(5)
        # Le DHT11 renvoie au maximum une mesure toute les 5s
        capteur.measure()
        # Récupère les mesures du capteur
        print(f"Temperature : {capteur.temperature():.1f}")
        print(f"Humidite    : {capteur.humidity():.1f}")
        print("*******************************")
        # Transmet la température sur la console de l'ordinateur
        
        url = 'http://charlesm.fr/test_enregistrement.php'
        values = {'lieu':"Salon",'temperature':capteur.temperature(),'humidite':capteur.humidity()}
        print(str(values))
        urequests.post(url,data=str(values))

      
    except OSError as e:
        print('Echec reception')
        # Si l'esp ne reçoit pas les mesures du capteur
```

I have no problem with the string of the data for the post method.Datas are in the good format. I try `str` function and `json.dumps`

*Here the code for the database*

```
CREATE TABLE `Temperature_humidite` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_modif` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lieu` text,
  `temperature` float ,
  `humidite` float 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

*Here the php code on my website*, I change the username and the MDP before posting it

```
    <?php
    try
                    {
    
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=db5010240052.hosting-data.io:3306;dbname=dbs8678052;charset=utf8', 'user', 'mdp',
array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ));
    $req = $bdd->prepare(" 
                INSERT INTO Temperature_humidite(lieu,temperature,humidite) 
                VALUES(:lieu, :temperature, :humidite)");
    $req->execute(array(
           'lieu' => $_POST["lieu"],
           'temperature' => $_POST["temperature"],
           'humidite' => $_POST["humidite"]
           ));
    
    
            $req->execute();
      
      
    
                    }
                        catch(Exception $e)
                    {
                            exit('<b>Catched exception at line '. $e->getLine() .' :</b> '. $e->getMessage());
                    }
    
    ?>
```

**Problem** => I don't understand why no data has been submitted, never. I have a huge DBB with null value everywhere. Where is the problem ?

Comment: Perhaps the data isn't posted in a format PHP expects. What does `print(str(values))` output? Also, in PHP, add some logging - make it write the output of `print_r($_POST, true);` to a file, and also write the output of `print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` to a file as well. Then show us what you get. I'm not familiar with the language or libraries being used to send the request, and how exactly they do things. But I do know that if they're sending data in JSON format, PHP won't read that into $_POST and so you'd need a different approach in that case. Please provide the info

Comment: Here the resultat of print =>  `{"lieu": "Salon", "humidite": 56, "temperature": 24}` , I add the two lines of code `print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` and `print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` => nothing appear

Comment: Thanks. If it sends the data to PHP in that exact format then you'll need to use the instructions in [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php) to allow PHP to read the data. PHP doesn't parse JSON content into the $_POST array (it will only do that with form-url-encoded content).

Answer (score 0):

@ADyson you were right,

I change the php code as following

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

try
                {

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=db5010240052.hosting-data.io:3306;dbname=dbs8678052;charset=utf8', user, mdp,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ));
$req = $bdd->prepare(" 
            INSERT INTO Temperature_humidite(lieu,temperature,humidite) 
            VALUES(:lieu, :temperature, :humidite)");
$req->execute(array(
       'lieu' => $data["lieu"],
       'temperature' => $data["temperature"],
       'humidite' => $data["humidite"]
       ));


        $req->execute();
  
  

                }
                    catch(Exception $e)
                {
                        exit('<b>Catched exception at line '. $e->getLine() .' :</b> '. $e->getMessage());
                }

?>
```

and now it's working. Data are added to the database